How to handle relative resource paths while using pyinstaller / auto py to exe?
I have python script that saves the log file and another csv to a relative resource path. The pyinstaller throws file not found error. The file structure of code is.
-ProjectFolder
|-common
|   |- commom.py
|-src
|   |- main.py
|   |- anotherclass.py
|-resources
|   |-output.logs
|   |-result.csv

Output exe directory
-ProjectFolder
|-output
|   |-main
|   |    |-main.exe
|   |    |-_internal
|   |    |     |-tons of packages and resources folder if I pass it while creating installer

How do I get this output to a folder besides the main folder of the executable?
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Projects\\CapstoneProject-Outkits\\output\\resources\\outkitsapicall.log'

Code inside main.py
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('../resources/outkitsapicall.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')


could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741

I did try that, but getting the same error. I am not able to debug as well since the log isn't being stored.

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path: str = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return base_path + relative_path

Add the required folders as additional folders while creating the executable. Call the resource/config files as below.
    keywords_path = commonutil.resource_path("/config/keywords.json")

Testing the locations.
logger.info("Current working directory:"+ os.getcwd())
base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
logger.info("Executable internal folder: "+ base_path)

